# Two Factor Authentication on 10.10.5 Yosemite

Tags: macos, authentication

I cannot find where to get my two factor authentication verification code from in settings on the Mac, neither is there any input field for me to type in the code. What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

You need to be running El Capitan or later.

See [Apple KB - Availability of two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205075)

If your Mac can run Yosemite, it can run El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

faced this in 2022, so wait for the 6-digit code to appear on one of your other devices. Then, re-enter "your password" + "6-digit authorization code" in the password field.

Example:

If your password is **MySuperPa55word** and code is **012938**, you must use **MySuperPa55word012938** instead of the real password.

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately I need the 2-factor authentication to get the upgrade to El Capitan or higher - nice feature, I guess I better install Windows ...